# 2005 Pontiac Grand Prix overheating

Tags: cooling-system, pontiac, overheating, cooling, grand-prix

I have recently bought a 2005 Grand Prix V6 non supercharged.

It overheats at idle and in park. I have had my head gasket and head resurfaced at Pepboys and replaced my radiator with a larger 1 inch thick radiator. The thermostat was also with a new OEM one.  Bled and burped my cooling system.  No leaks anywhere.  Bypassed the heater and capped the hosses.  The car still wants to climb to the red.  It has Dextron 50/50 and has been flushed.  Both fans kick on with a good amount of breeze.

***How can I troubleshoot my cooling system to discover what the issue might be with the continued overheating?***

Comment: Does the car exhibit any other symptoms of overheating, such as steaming or bubbles into the overflow? Also, if it shows as overheating and you move the vehicle (take it out for a drive) the temp goes down?

Comment: If i take it for a drive the temp risses considerbally faster it doesn't seem to be bubbling in resivor i can tell its cycling from when i burped it i could see the difference in temp of the fluid

Comment: Are you sure the thermostat went back in correctly? If it's upside down it can cause problems.

Comment: I did it about a hour ago with the half with the spring into the engine and other half towards hose

Comment: How did you go about burping the engine?

Comment: Took Cap off radiator opened valve on thermostat open car running till water came from valve steadily and then i tightened it and continued to run until air stopped coming throgh filler neck opened valve again till water came out shut valve and put cap back on turned car off let cool till qaurter of temp gauge ran it at idle and gauge eventually starts to climb above 3/4 of gauge

Comment: Try and do the same thing again, only this time, put the car in a nose up attitude. Either up on car ramps or on an incline. I'm suspecting you still have air in the system.

Comment: Would poping up on a curb work

Comment: It should, just don't bang up the front end of your car doing so. ;-)

Comment: I went and got a thermostat that open up at 180 and reburped it with front on jack stands still no good

Comment: Something has to be blocking coolant flow then. Does the heater run hot? If so, does it help to blow the heater (slow the raise in temperature any)? It would be hard to tell, but wondering if they put the wrong head gaskets in or if there isn't coolant flow between the block and heads due to something which wasn't done right ... not suggesting you tear it down and put new gaskets on, though. Just not sure what's going on. Maybe someone else will see something I've missed.

Comment: Possibly water pump? Try running without a thermostat.  Does the radiator get hot at the inlet?